# A uniq number assocciated with every symbolic variable in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, uniq

I am generating some symbolic sympy variables:

```
from sympy import symarray 
A=symarray('A' ,(7,2))
B=symarray('B' ,(4,8))
C=symarray('C' ,(3,4))
```

So I totally have `7*2 + 4*8 + 3*4 = 58` symbolic variables. I want each one of these variables includes a unique number ranging from `0` to `57`:

```
print((A[3,1]).uniq_number)
print((B[4,7]).uniq_number)
print((C[2,2]).uniq_number)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe create a single flat numpy array for `[A, B, C]` and use the index.